# Syntactic differences in cp -r and how to overcome them

Tags: linux, command-line, cp, history

Let's say we are in a blank directory.  Then, the following commands:

```
mkdir dir1
cp -r dir1 dir2
```

Yield two (blank) directories, `dir1` and `dir2`, where `dir2` has been created as a copy of `dir1`.  However, if we do this:

```
mkdir dir1
mkdir dir2
cp -r dir1 dir2
```

Then we instead find that `dir1` has now been put inside `dir2`.  This means that **the exact same `cp` command behaves differently depending on whether the destination directory exists**.  If it does, then the `cp` command is doing the same as this:

```
mkdir dir1
mkdir dir2
cp -r dir1 dir2/.
```

This seems extremely counter-intuitive to me.  I would have expected that `cp -r dir1 dir2` (when `dir2` already exists) would remove the existing `dir2` (and any contents) and replace it with `dir1`, since this is the behavior when `cp` is used for two files.  I understand that recursive copies are themselves a bit different because of how directories exist in Linux (and more broadly in Unix-like systems), but I'm looking for some more explanation on *why* this behavior was chosen.  Bonus points if you can point me to a way to ensure `cp` behaves as I had expected (without having to, say,  test for and remove the destination directory beforehand).  I tried a few `cp` options without any luck.  And I suppose I'll accept `rsync` solutions for the sake of others that happen upon this question who don't know that command.

In case this behavior is not universal, I'm on CentOS, using bash.

Comment: What is counter intuitive about that? If shoot an arrow at a tree something happens, if I shoot the same arrow in the same direction but someone is standing in front of the tree something else happens. Same program different data, different outcome.

Comment: "I would have expected that cp -r dir1 dir2 (when dir2 already exists) would remove the existing dir2 (and any contents).." **What?** Why? I can understand overwritting files, but removing any pre-existing files as well? O.o

Comment: @anthon But I haven't provided different inputs.  In your example, you're shooting an arrow _in a constant direction_, not at a tree.  @muru I wouldn't expect `cp file1 file2` to append if `file2` exists, I expect it to overwrite.  My basis for anticipated behavior is on a literal interpretation of the syntax and on what is done with files, though other users may expect differently.

Comment: Could the down-voter please provide some feedback on how I could improve the question?

Comment: @TTT you can only notify one user in a comment. By that logic, since `> file` truncates a file, shouldn't `>directory` be equivalent to `rm -r directory; mkdir directory`?

Comment: @muru thanks.  That's a tricky one, since `>` redirection is placing contents and not files/directories themselves, I wouldn't expect that behavior to be possible (it isn't) since you'd be writing data directly to a directory, rather than a file in a directory.  My idea of `cp -r` overwriting isn't that I think that behavior is _better_, but just that it's consistent.  I'd be equally content if `cp file1 file2` and `cp -r dir1 dir2` both appended.  But, neither do.  Instead, one (over)writes while the other's behavior depends on the situation.

Comment: @TTT The problem is directories and files are treated differently in enough commands (e.g., `ls` by default, `rm`, `touch` when given a non-existent directory as argument, etc.) that that argument doesn't hold water.

Comment: Similar question I asked a bit later but got more visibility: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228597

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour you're looking for is a [special case](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html):

> ```
> cp -R [-H|-L|-P] [-fip] source_file... target
> ```
>
> [This] form is denoted by two or more operands where the -R option is specified. The cp utility shall copy each file in the file hierarchy rooted in each source_file to a destination path named as follows:
>
> - If target exists and names an existing directory, the name of the corresponding destination path for each file in the file hierarchy shall be the concatenation of target, a single `<slash>` character if target did not end in a `<slash>`, and the pathname of the file relative to the directory containing source_file.
> - If target does not exist and two operands are specified, the name of the corresponding destination path for source_file shall be target; the name of the corresponding destination path for all other files in the file hierarchy shall be the concatenation of target, a `<slash>` character, and the pathname of the file relative to source_file.
>
> It shall be an error if target does not exist and more than two operands are specified ...

Therefore I'd say it's not possible to make `cp` do what you want.

---

Since your expected behaviour is "`cp -r dir1 dir2` (when `dir2` already exists) would remove the existing `dir2` (and any contents) and replace it with `dir1`":

```
rm -rf dir2 && cp -r dir1 dir2
```

You don't even need to check if `dir2` exists.

---

The `rsync` solution would be adding a trailing `/` to the source so that it doesn't copy `dir1` itself into `dir2` but copies the content of `dir1` to `dir2` (it will still keep existing files in `dir2`):

```
$ tree dir*
dir1
└── test.txt
dir2
└── test2.txt

0 directories, 2 file
$ rsync -a dir1/ dir2
$ tree dir*           
dir1
└── test.txt
dir2
└── test.txt
└── test2.txt

0 directories, 3 files
$ rm -r dir2          
$ rsync -a dir1/ dir2
$ tree dir*           
dir1
└── test.txt
dir2
└── test.txt

0 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: This answer, combined with your comments on inconsistent behaviors between directories and files for other commands answers my question in full.

Answer (score 0):

cp have several forms :

```
   cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
   cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
   cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
```

when you are doing `cp -r dir1 dir2` your are expecting an implicit evaluation of the second argument.

- If the second argument is a name that does not exist in the file system, cp will interpret it as a DEST and will create it, copyind dir1 ***as*** dir2.
- if it exist already, it is interpreted as a DIRECTORY and thus copy dir1 ***into*** it.

---

If you are not sure of you initial state, and want to avoid the multiple interpretation possible, you can simply explicit it with the `-T` option :

```
$ tree dir*
dir1
└── test.txt
dir2
└── test2.txt

0 directories, 2 file
$ cp -r dir1 -T dir2
$ tree dir*           
dir1
└── test.txt
dir2
└── test.txt

0 directories, 3 files
$ rm -r dir2          
$ cp -r dir1 -T dir2
$ tree dir*           
dir1
└── test.txt
dir2
└── test.txt

0 directories, 2 files
```